# Use regex and matplotlib to plot graphs for given data

Tags: python, regex, pandas, matplotlib

I have a set of data that looks like this

```
codebit 00 all words BL 0
running test 

DATA1
0.000  1.23
0.050 11.34
0.100 21.26
.....

codebit 01 all words BL 1
running test 

DATA1
0.000   0.2
0.050 11.68
0.100 12.21
....
```

What I need is a regex to find the **codebit** and the **BL** and then start looking for the word "DATA1" (this is common in all the data sets) and take the data below it to make plots with different names. 
What I have implemented is from DATA1 part. It works when there is small sets of data but for bigger sets it will be time consuming. I needed an automated way to do it. My code looks like this :

```
file = pd.read_table('sample.txt')
file[['time', 'instances']] = file['DATA1'].str.split(expand=True)

dist = file["instances"].tolist()
t = file["time"].tolist()
t= list(map(float,t))
dist = list(map(int, dist))

plt.plot(t,dist)
plt.yscale('log')
plt.title("PLOT")
plt.xlabel("TIME")
plt.ylabel("INSTANCES")
pylab.show()
```

With this code, I copy the piece of data after DATA1 and paste it into a sample.txt file and run my code. And it gives me the plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you really need a regex here. From the sample you have provided looks like `codebit` and `BL` are properly separated with a space, therefore I think a `split()` will suffice here. Let me know if you think otherwise.

TXT file **sample_v1.txt**

```
codebit 00 all words BL 0
running test

DATA1
0.000000e+00 1.000475e+00
2.040816e+00 1.022914e+00
4.081633e+00 1.719943e+00
...

codebit 01 all words BL 1
running test

DATA1
0.000000e+00 3.481705e+00
2.040816e+00 7.774324e+00
4.081633e+00 8.872994e+00
...

codebit 02 all words BL 2
running test

DATA1
0.000000e+00 1.261371e+00
2.040816e+00 3.516784e+00
4.081633e+00 5.722052e+00
...

codebit 03 all words BL 3
running test

DATA1
0.000000e+00 6.245599e+00
2.040816e+00 1.036477e+01
4.081633e+00 1.328821e+01
...
```

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_table('sample_v1.txt', header=None)

print(df)

# find the indices so they can be used as markers later
codebit_list = list(df.loc[df[0].str.startswith("codebit")].index)
data1_list = list(df.loc[df[0].str.startswith("DATA1")].index)

code_list = []
for cl in codebit_list:
    # split row to extract 'codebit' and 'BL' data
    cl_split = df.iloc[cl].str.split()
    code_list.append((cl_split[0][1],cl_split[0][-1]))

# remove first element and add frame lenght here to
# facilitate the for loop boundaries later
codebit_list.pop(0)
codebit_list.extend([len(df)])

data_xy = []
for k in zip(data1_list, codebit_list):
    # get plot data between the markers
    h = df[k[0] + 1:k[1]]
    data_xy.append(h[0].str.split(expand=True).astype("float"))

for idx, dxy in enumerate(data_xy):
    labels = "codebit={} | BL={}".format(code_list[idx][0], code_list[idx][1])
    plt.plot(dxy[0], dxy[1], label=labels)
    plt.legend()
    plt.yscale('log')
    plt.grid(alpha=0.3)

plt.title("PLOT")
plt.xlabel("TIME")
plt.ylabel("INSTANCES")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @n1colas.m 
This worked and was much easier than regex. Thank you !